# Why do some songs in my iTunes library stop prematurely and go to the next song?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, music

For the past couple of weeks a whole bunch of the songs from my iTunes library stop early and skip to the next song (just as if it was at the end of the song). Although the point where it skips varies for each song (for one song it is 2:32, another is 2:46), it will always skip at the same point for each song.

A while back I ran [BPMer](http://wildbits.com/bpmer/) and, although it crashed halfway through, it did not appear to corrupt my music the way it is now.

A few days ago I backed up my iTunes library and reformatted my hard drive (for a completely unrelated issue) and reinstalled OS X from scratch. The problem was happening before and after the reinstall.

This problem also persists when the music is synced across to my iPod touch running 3.0. Listening to the same troublesome songs in my iPod causes them to end prematurely. However, I can listen to the whole song using Quicklook, so the problem must be with my iTunes library or something.

Comment: Related on Ask Different: [iTunes 10.5.3.3 - songs ending early](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/40589/72620)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Music options in iTunes inlcude a stop time.  Ctrl-click->Get Info->Options will show you if these have be changed, perhaps by BPMer.

If that is the case, you can change the stop time in the info box for each song.  If you don't mind losing play counts and ratings, you can re-import your music.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem. I checked the stop time. It was 1) not checked, and 2) it was the correct time for when the song should have stopped.  The song was stopping about 10 seconds before. I had another song from the same album that also stopped short.

These were songs purchased from the iTunes Store, not ripped.

The same song played correctly to the end on another computer.  I recently transferred my music to a new computer.

On a hunch, I wondered if something was corrupted in the iTunes library file (which is an XML file).

**I deleted the songs from the library, leaving the files where they were (not putting them in the recycle bin).  Then I dragged those two songs back into iTunes so they would be reinserted into the library.**

**Now they play perfectly fine!!**

Comment: Same problem here (not stop time related). A group of files imported together were stuck at 94 s. I reimported them: some worked, some didn't (at another time point). When converted from MP3 to AAC (using Audacity) and imported again, all worked. Seems one of these problems that are nearly impossible to track down...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your files are not corrupted, and is this related to something completely different.

Could check the following:

in iTunes there is an option under preferences (tab 'playback') named 'Crossfade' 
See whether it is turned on. If so, turn it of and check again if songs stop early.
I was confronted with this when I downloaded a new version of iTunes, even though the setting was not set before.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue after having to recreate my entire library from a backup (a hard drive had failed).

This was on a PC, and the solution I found was to stop itunes, delete the itunes .itl file, restart itunes and let it rebuild the library from the xml file (make sure that the xml file exists and is up to date before doing this).

I did this after checking there was nothing wrong with the files themselves (if I re-added a file, it was fine), and also checking that no 'odd' options had been set on the files (e.g. a particular stop time).

You will lose some file info doing this (last played, album artwork), but the artwork will be rebuilt (generally correctly, although some 'odd' choices can occur).

Comment: On El Capitan with iTunes 12.5.1, there is no option to rebuild the library from xml file.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed iTunes ending songs early on Windows 10 by exporting my library as an XML file and re-importing it as a playlist. This had the benefit of preserving my song metadata, playlists, and folder structure.

1. In iTunes select *File > Library > Export Library*.
2. Save your library as an XML file somewhere.
3. Close iTunes.
4. Open your iTunes folder (`%UserProfile%\Music\iTunes`)
5. Rename `iTunes Library.itl` to `iTunes Library (backup).itl`.
6. Open iTunes. (*You should have an empty library*)
7. Select *File > Library > Import Playlist*
8. Open the library file you saved in step 2.
9. Wait for the import to complete.